# Text opens in wrong window tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to insert text into a new window that opens on a user's button click. However, when I try this, the textbox that I want to open in the **new window** opens up in the **first window**. See image below:

[image: Image of where text is in the wrong window]

I have done my research and one answer I have come across is that I am sharing the 'Tk' widget too many times.

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = Text(root, height=4, width=100)
text.pack()
text.insert(END, "The family car starting price is £24060 including VAT and 
CO2 taxes")
text.insert(END, "\nThe sports car starting price is £30115 including VAT 
and CO2 taxes")
text.insert(END, "\nThe suv car starting price is £36100 including VAT and 
CO2 taxes")

def family_create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.title("family Exterior colour")

    text = Text(root, height=4, width=100)
    text.pack()
    text.insert(END, "Hello")

    def newwindow():
        window = tk.Toplevel(root)
        window.title("New window")

    greyex = PhotoImage(file="vwfamilygrey.png")
    greyexlabel = Button(window, image=greyex)
    greyexbutton = Button(window, image=greyex, command=newwindow)
    greyexbutton.pack()
    window.mainloop()

familycar = PhotoImage(file = "VW family car.png")
familylabel = Button(root, image=familycar)
familybutton = Button(root, image=familycar, command=family_create_window)

familybutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

As soon as the user clicks on the image of the family car, what I want to happen is for a new window with images to open with the text 'hello' at the top of the window.

The 'greyex' is the exterior colour for additional help.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You probably need to place your text in the correct window: replace `    text = Text(root, height=4, width=100)`, with `    text = Text(window, height=4, width=100)`

Comment: Yep! I have tried that too and it works perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the *parent widget* of the `Text` widget which says "hello" from `root` to `window`. This will make the Text widget appear on the new Window instead of the main window.

Example:

```
def family_create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.title("family Exterior colour")

    text = Text(window, height=4, width=100)  # Switch root to window
    text.pack()
    text.insert(END, "Hello")
```

Hope I helped

Comment: That works perfectly fine thank you!. The message now displays at the top of the new window. Thanks again!